# Display 3 buttons at the same level inside <td> element

Tags: css

I have 3 buttons inside a td element that I want to display at he same line :

[my 3 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8c0dX.png)

Here is my html and css code :

```
<div class="threeButtons">
            <div class="jimu-btn"
                style="height:38px;width:85px;display:block;margin-right: 110px;" 
                data-placement="bottom">Importer
            </div>
            <div class="jimu-btn"
                 style="height: 38px; width: 99px; display: block; margin-right: 120px;">Déplacer vers
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;height:38px;width:90px;display:block;margin-right: 10px;" class="jimu-btn">Désassocier
            </div>
</div>
```

```
.jimu-btn {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    min-width: 30px;
    background-color: #485566;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Does anyone know how to do that? I am new to css. Thanks in advance

Comment: remove all inline styles and just rely on class

Comment: .jimu-btn { display: inline-block; } (not "block"!), and no floats

Comment: I don't see any td element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ehere's a solution using CSS Flexbox

I changed your html and CSS too like this:

```css
.threeButtons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.jimu-btn {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 30px;
  background-color: #485566;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="threeButtons">
  <div class="jimu-btn">Importer</div>
  <div class="jimu-btn">Déplacer vers</div>
  <div class="jimu-btn">Désassocier</div>
</div>
```

I've used flexbox to keep the element neat and without all that inline styles.

Here's a solution, with no px units and some transition on hover:

```css
.threeButtons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

button {
  transition: all linear .3s;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .4rem;
  width: 7rem;
  background-color: #485566;
  color: #ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #566566;
}
```

```html
<div class="threeButtons">
  <button>Importer</button>
  <button>Déplacer vers</button>
  <button>Désassocier</button>
</div>
```

Hope it help!
Bye

EDIT:  [a link to MDN for understanding CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)